# Relative path in Lua script failing

Tags: lua, relative-path

So, here's one of those too-simple-to-fail bugs that we all hate.

I have a .lua file that, among other things, tries to load an image via Love's newImageData function (and place it into a button):

```
back_button = buttonmanager.createButton("back", love.image.newImageData("../Images/BackButton.png"), width-200, height-105)
```

Love fails to load, throwing this error:

```
./frame.lua:5: Could not open file ../Images/BackButton.png. Does not exist.
```

I've gone through the stupid-mistakes process ("well, does it actually exist? Where is the folder?" etc) -- the file exists, is in the Images folder, which is one level up -- I can even say "ls ../Images/BackButton.png" from the directory this script sits in, and it outputs BackButton.png as I'd expect.

Is there some weird relative pathing issue I need to watch out for? I tried changing it to an absolute path and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The [love.filesystem](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem) module restricts access to files in certain locations:

> This module provides access to Files in two places, and two places only:
>
> ```
> * The root folder of the .love-file. (Alternatively a directory).
> * The root folder of the write directory.
> ```

Is the `../Images` directory outside of your game's folder/archive?